# SQL function with square roots causes problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is erroring out:

```
SET @SumDiff = @SitesSum - (select power(SUM(Sums),2)/@NumSites from @SiteSums)
SET @SE = power((@SumDiff/(@NumSites - 1)),0.5)/power(@NumSites,0.5)
```

This function works most of the time, but I get an error some times.
Here are the values when i have the problem.
`SUM(Sums) = .01` so squared = `.001`
`@NumSites = 2`
`@SiteSum = 0`

The value from this part:
`select power(@Sums,2)/@NumSites from @SiteSums`
comes out as `5E-05` which would match the value expected, .00005

When I try to set @SE it's basically finding the square root of (.00005 / 1)/ square root of 2 (1.4142135623731).

Should be something like 3.535533905932725. But I get the message:

```
Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 306  
An invalid floating point operation occurred.
```

Is .00005 too small to divide in SQL? Could I do a cast? This isn't always going to be working with decimals, mostly larger numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, using your values this:

```
SET @SumDiff = @SitesSum - (select power(SUM(Sums),2)/@NumSites from @SiteSums)
```

..results in `@SumDiff` being set to `-5E-05`, and *not* `5E-05`.

So when you then do:

```
power((@SumDiff/(@NumSites - 1)),0.5)
```

..you are trying to take the square root of a negative number which is invalid (undefined) for a Real number.

The `ABS(..)` function can fix this for you:

```
SET @SE = power((ABS(@SumDiff)/(@NumSites - 1)),0.5)/power(@NumSites,0.5)
```